Getting client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe after adding ServerAliveInterval 600
I added this
Host *

ServerAliveInterval 600

to my ~/.ssh/config file and I am still getting the error.
terminal throws the error after a minute of inactivity, connecting to a remote server ssh -p 2220 bandit12@bandit.labs.overthewire.org.
Checked the remote servers etc/ssh/sshd.config file, and it doesn't have a ClientAliveInterval configuration.

I switched my network
provider, which seemed to solve the issue. Not sure why
